# Capitalize the first word (or optionally all the words) of a sentence in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

I am trying to capitalize words of a string in the angular 2 template (aka view) but I get the following error in the console and the application does not load (displays a blank page):

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe
>   'capitalize' could not be found

I am trying to do the following. The below examples use a literal string for illustration. In reality, the string will be a variable in the angular 2 component.

1. Capitalize only the first word of the sentence if no argument is provided.

> ```
>  {{ 'heLlo woRld' | capitalize }} // outputs "HeLlo woRld" - Only "H" is capitalized
> ```

2. Capitalize all words of the string by passing the argument 'all'.

> {{ 'heLlo woRld' | capitalize:'all' }}   // outputs "HeLlo WoRld" -
>   Both "H" and "W" are capitalized

3. Some other edge cases that are to be satisfied are:

> ```
>  {{ 'a' | capitalize }}                   // outputs "A"
>
>  {{ 'a' | capitalize:'all' }}             // outputs "A"
>
>  {{ '' | capitalize }}                    // outputs nothing
>
>  {{ '' | capitalize:'all' }}              // outputs nothing
>
>  {{ null | capitalize }}                  // outputs nothing
>
>  {{ null | capitalize:'all' }}            // outputs nothing
> ```

NOTE: Please note that solution should be pure JS based (no csss) and does not have to be unicode compliant, but should conform to best practices, and particularly:

1. NO THIRD PARTY LIBRARY(such as jQuery, underscore, lodash) should be used
2. AND code should conform to both Typescript and ES6 standards.

NOTE: Removed the phrase "No ES3 or ES5 code" as this phrase was causing some confusion and also added the error that I was getting.

Comment: what did you try so far? seems like yet another „do it for free for me“ „question“ besides.. no es3 or es5… you kidding right?

Comment: All ES3 and ES5 code **is already** ES6 by definition.

Comment: Is where you got stuck the logic of capitalization, or the mechanics of writing an Angular pipe, or both/

Comment: Edited question to display error and removed the phrase "No ES3 or ES5 code" as this was causing some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I had assumed that angular 2 provides a "capitalize" pipe out of the box (just as it provides the "uppercase" pipe). So, to resolve the problem, created a "capitalize" pipe as follows:

1. Create a file called: **capitalize.pipe.ts**

Alternately, if you are using angular-cli, then you can generate the above file using the command: **ng g pipe capitalize**

NOTE: You will also have to modify your modulg file(e.g. home.module.ts) to include the newly created/generated pipe.

2. Modify the newly created/generated file as follows:

> ```
> import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
>
> // To be DRY, define a reusable function that converts a 
> // (word or sentence) to title case
>
> const toTitleCase = (value) => {
>   return value.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);
>   // alternately, can also use this: 
>   // return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
> };
>
> @Pipe({
>   name: 'capitalize'
> })
> export class CapitalizePipe implements PipeTransform {
>
>   transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
>     if (value) {
>       if (args === 'all') {
>         return value.split(' ').map(toTitleCase).join(' ');
>       } else {
>         return toTitleCase(value);
>       }
>     }
>     return value;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

3. Once you have done the above, then you can use the pipe from your template (aka view) as follows:

> {{ 'heLlo woRld' | capitalize }}         // outputs "HeLlo woRld" -
>   Only "H" is capitalized
>
> {{ 'heLlo woRld' | capitalize:'all' }}   // outputs "HeLlo WoRld" -
>   Both "H" and "W" are capitalized

Comment: Great. Let's write code which will break in unforeseen ways sometime in the future, as long as it's some other poor schmuck who has to fix it, not us. By the way, you used **lots** of ES3 and ES5 in your code. For instance, the `if` and `return` statements are both ES3, and `.map` is ES5.

Comment: I see your point about ES3 and ES5 and I have edited my question to remove this phrase. However, so far as "Unicode" is concerned, well, at least for my use case, it's not a requirement and the above solution satisfies my overall requirements.

Answer (score 0):

it will capitalize first letter of each word :

```js
function cap_words(str){
    str=str.split(" ")
    for(var i=0 ; i<str.length ;i++){
        str[i]= str[i][0].toUpperCase()+str[i].substring(1)
    }
    return str.join(" ")
}


console.log(cap_words("and this is a test !"))
```